# Drawn custom items sometimes chopped off in QGraphicsScene

Tags: c++, qt

I have a custom graphics item, that is inherting from `QGraphicsEllipseItem`. Specifically, my custom item is just a circle with a label attached to it (let me call it a "vertex"). I understand the idea: inherit from the base class, implement certain methods, and you are done.

The header is here:

```
#ifndef VERTEX_H
#define VERTEX_H

#include <QPointF>
#include <QGraphicsEllipseItem>

class Vertex : public QGraphicsEllipseItem
{
public:
    Vertex(const QPointF& pos, int label, int size = 20) : pos_(pos), label_(label), size_(size)  { }

    QRectF boundingRect() const;

protected:
    virtual void paint(QPainter* painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem* option, QWidget* widget = 0);

private:
    QPointF pos_;
    int label_;
    int size_;
};

#endif // VERTEX_H
```

The implementations here:

```
// vertex.cpp
#include "vertex.h"
#include <QPainter>

QRectF Vertex::boundingRect() const
{
    return QGraphicsEllipseItem(pos_.x(), pos_.y(), size_, size_).boundingRect();
}

void Vertex::paint(QPainter* painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem* option, QWidget* widget)
{
    painter->drawEllipse(pos_, size_, size_);
    painter->drawText(pos_, QString::number(label_));
}
```

Because my object really *is* an ellipse, I'd like to exploit the bounding rectangle implementation in an ellipse. However, something seems to be off when I draw things. In particular, I might see something like this:

[image]

(The above is cropped from a QGraphicsScene).

1. Is my implementation for `boundingRect` off?
2. Is something else causing "bad" drawing? I draw a Vertex when the user clicks the QGraphicsScene, so the `QPointF` argument to the constructor of `Vertex` is provided from `mouseEvent->scenePos();`, where mouseEvent is of type `QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you don't gain anything form and don't really need to inherit `QGraphicsEllipseItem`, it is better to start on a clean slate, just inherit `QGraphicsItem`. The stock ellipse item doesn't draw the ellipse from a center point and radius, so its bounding rect implementation will not match what you are drawing.

Since you essentially draw a circle with a center and radius, your correct bounding rect implementation should return a `QRectF(pos_.x() - size_ / 2, pos.y() - size_ /2, size_, size_)`.

Your current implementation doesn't return a rectangle which covers your item, instead it begins at its center and goes far outside:

[image]

OK, a little more help:

- distinguish between absolute and relative coordinates - the point that comes from your mouse click will not actually be used to set the center of the circle, but the position of the graphics item
- the circle's center will actually be relative to the item, so it will be `QPointF(radius, radius)`, in your case half of `size_`
- you don't really need to store the center point
- if your bounding rectangle implementation is correct everything will draw correctly
- if you want the items to overlap, you will have to set a brush for the painter, otherwise it will only draw the outline of the circle

So creating a circle at the desired position and diameter and drawing it boils down to something like this:

```
class Circle : public QGraphicsItem {
public:
    Circle(QPointF c, int r) {
        setPos(QPointF(c.x() - r, c.y() - r));
        radius = r;
    }
    QRectF boundingRect() const { return QRectF(pos(), pos() + QPointF(radius * 2, radius * 2)); }
    void paint(QPainter* painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem* option, QWidget* widget = 0) {
        painter->setBrush(Qt::white);
        painter->drawEllipse(boundingRect());
        painter->drawText(boundingRect().center(), "C");
    }
private:
    int radius;
};
```

And it all draws correctly now:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! It seems as if the circles do draw correctly now. But actually, it also seems it is a bit hard to predict *where* the circles are actually drawn.  When I click a spot, the circle might appear many inches away from the clicked spot. Am I correct in supplying `mouseEvent->scenePos();` as an argument to the Circle?

Comment: It really depends, you might need to map the coordinate to the scene, I haven't really used the graphics scene/view/item stack. Judging by the behavior you are describing, you will need to map the position. The reason it fluctuates is probably because the view position changes to accommodate newly added items. When correctly mapped, the circle center should appear right where you click.

Comment: Don't expect Qt's mapping methods to work in any sane manner BTW. I tried mapToScene and it produces total nonsense. Do it manually. Also, unless you like pain and suffering, I suggest to not use qgraphics scene/view/item stack and instead go for QML. It is tremendously easier and faster to use.